# VBScript to convert DOC to DOCX without Compatibility Mode enabled

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, docx, doc

My VBScript below converts a Word DOC to DOCX:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fullpath = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
justpath = Left(fullpath, InStrRev(fullpath, "\"))
basename = oFSO.GetBaseName(fullpath)
doxpath = justpath & basename & ".docx" 
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open(fullpath)
doc.SaveAs2 doxpath, 16
doc.Close
oWord.Quit
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

However when I open the output DOCX it says "[Compatibility Mode]" at the top. Is there some property I can set or method to call before/during/after the SaveAs2 call so that doesn't happen?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `SaveAs2()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2

Comment: Yes. But that's a VBA page and the compatibility option is at the end of a long list of arguments and there is no way to specify named arguments in VBS and I don't feel like specifying all the arguments.

Comment: You can skip optional arguments that you don't want to supply, just write the respective number of empty commas: `.SomeMethod RequiredArg, , , , , , OptionalArg`.

Comment: Niiice. Did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works now. Thanks Tomalak!

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fullpath = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
justpath = Left(fullpath, InStrRev(fullpath, "\"))
basename = oFSO.GetBaseName(fullpath)
doxpath = justpath & basename & ".docx" 
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = oWord.Documents.Open(fullpath)
'FileFormat = wdFormatDocumentDefault = 16 = Word default document file format. For Word, this is the DOCX format.
'CompatibilityMode = wdCurrent = 65535 = Compatibility mode equivalent to the latest version of Word.
doc.SaveAs2 doxpath, 16, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 65535
doc.Close
oWord.Quit
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: I tend to define `Const wdCurrent = 65535` and use the constant in the rest of the code. This can save the explanatory comment and is less spooky than magic numbers in your method calls.